# ^(){} syntax in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I have seen some strange syntax like

```
self.myProperties = ^(){};
```

I wonder what is meaning of this ?

Comment: that is a void block, my friend.

Comment: Can't you see it's a man with a big nose laughing?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

It's a block taking no parameters, returning nothing, doing nothing.

Check for reference:
http://fuckingblocksyntax.com

Answer (score 1):

The expression right of the equation sign is an empty lambda expression in objective-c (or C respectively). 
In the objective-c/C community often referred to as a block.

And you assign this "anonymous function entry point" to your property `myProperties`.

You can later pass its value to wherever a lambda expression/block is expected. Or you can call it of course. 
Calling syntax should be

```
self.myProperties();
```

as it does not take any parameters nor does it return anything. And of course it does not do anything at all. But it should compile and run just fine.